# How can I test the value of multiple keys at once in a node affinity rule? Is there a key wildcard?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Let's assume I have a node labeled with the labels `myKey1: 2`, `myKey2: 5`, `myKey3: 3`, `myKey4: 6`. I now want to check if one of those labels has a value greater than 4 and if so schedule my workload on this node. For that I use the following `nodeAffinity` rule:

```yaml
 spec:
   containers:
   - name: wl1
     image: myImage:latest
     imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  affinity:
     nodeAffinity:
       requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
         nodeSelectorTerms:
         - matchExpressions:
           - key: myKey1
             operator: Gt
             values:
             - 4
         nodeSelectorTerms:
         - matchExpressions:
           - key: myKey2
             operator: Gt
             values:
             - 4
         nodeSelectorTerms:
         - matchExpressions:
           - key: myKey3
             operator: Gt
             values:
             - 4
         nodeSelectorTerms:
         - matchExpressions:
           - key: myKey4
             operator: Gt
             values:
             - 4
```

I would instead love to use something shorter to be able to address a bunch of similar labels like e.g.

```yaml
  affinity:
     nodeAffinity:
       requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
         nodeSelectorTerms:
         - matchExpressions:
           - key: myKey*
             operator: Gt
             values:
             - 4
```

so basically using a `key`-wildcard and the different checks connected via a logical `OR`. Is this possible or is there another solution to check the value of multiple similar labels?

Comment: I would add an extra label to all nodes, which should match. I think that was the simplest solution. Was that also a solution for you? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/

Comment: @MatthiasM unfortunately, this solution does not work in my case. The labels are given and the values set depending on features of different HW components of the same HW entity of the node. If one of these components then match my Pod's container requirement, it should be scheduled there.

Answer (score 2):

As [Matthias M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1909531/matthias-m) wrote in the comment:

> I would add an extra label to all nodes, which should match. I think that was the simplest solution. Was that also a solution for you? [kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)

In your situation, it will actually be easier to just add another key and check only one condition. Alternatively, you can try to use [set-based values](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#resources-that-support-set-based-requirements):

> Newer resources, such as  [`Job`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/),  [`Deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/),  [`ReplicaSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/), and  [`DaemonSet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/), support  *set-based*  requirements as well.

```yaml
selector:
  matchLabels:
    component: redis
  matchExpressions:
    - {key: tier, operator: In, values: [cache]}
    - {key: environment, operator: NotIn, values: [dev]}
```

> `matchLabels`  is a map of  `{key,value}`  pairs. A single  `{key,value}`  in the  `matchLabels`  map is equivalent to an element of  `matchExpressions`, whose  `key`  field is "key", the  `operator`  is "In", and the  `values`  array contains only "value".  `matchExpressions`  is a list of pod selector requirements. Valid operators include In, NotIn, Exists, and DoesNotExist. The values set must be non-empty in the case of In and NotIn. All of the requirements, from both  `matchLabels`  and  `matchExpressions`  are ANDed together -- they must all be satisfied in order to match.

For more about it read also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002334/kubernetes-node-selector-regex).

Comment: The set-based requirements seem to not work since I can't consolidate my different labels to one and also need to ensure that my Pod requirement is greater or equal to the keys' values.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60809356/15407542) to see how should be created.